# Unity: Smooth camera movement on UI button click

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, onclick

I'm trying to make the camera move to a certain position after clicking a UI button.
For the positioning, I use empty game objects' (CameraPositionStart and CameraPositionFinish) coordinates.
For some reason, the camera just teleports to the position needed instead of smoothly moving to it.
Here's my code:

```
using UnityEngine; 
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CameraMover : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public Button ButtonStartNew;
    public GameObject CameraPositionStart;
    public GameObject CameraPositionFinish;

    private void Update()
    {
        ButtonStartNew.onClick.AddListener(moveCamera);
    }

    public void moveCamera()
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, CameraPositionFinish.transform.position, Time.deltaTime * speed);
    }
}
```

Comment: For smooth movement you have to call that line in update function and also it is best practice to AddListener in onenable or start function rather than update function

Comment: @Jaimin thank you, I did everything as you said. The camera started to move smoothly but now the movement starts as soon as the Play mode is on.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is likely caused because of two reasons.

The method `Update` is executed once every frame. Here **every frame** you are adding an additional call that should be made when you click the button on the UI. The result of this, I suspect, is that when the several hundred calls to `moveCamera` all happen at the same time, and despite `moveCamera` only moving the transform by `Lerp(Time.DeltaTime * Speed)`  -- the object moves **closer**(since you're lerping) instantly because you're calling it a bunch.

```cs
private void Update()
{
    ButtonStartNew.onClick.AddListener(moveCamera);
}
```

Consider only adding one call to `moveCamera` to the on click event. We can do this in `Start` or `Awake` since they're only called once.

```cs
private void Start()
{
    ButtonStartNew.onClick.AddListener(moveCamera);
}
```

However this along does not solve the problem. Because if we do that `moveCamera` will only be called once and the result would be the camera would move very slightly toward the target and stop.

Consider implementing a `Coroutine` that will move the transform over time(every frame) until it has reached the target.

```cs
private void moveCamera()
{
    // A coroutine runs every frame until it stops returning values
    StartCoroutine(MoveCamera);
}

private IEnumerator MoveCamera()
{
    // check the distance and see if we still need to move towards the destination ​
    while(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, CameraPositionFinish.transform.position) > 1.0f)
   ​{

       transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, CameraPositionFinish.transform.position, Time.deltaTime * speed);
   
       // Return  nothing meaningful and wait until next frame​
       yield return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @DekuDesu, the coroutine was helpful!